# Why do I get TargetInvocationException in my threaded C# application?

Tags: c#, multithreading, delegates

Here is the code (in a simple form):

```
delegate DataTable Functie();
Functie deleg;

DataTable find1()
{
    return new DataTable();
}
DataTable find2()
{
    return new DataTable();
}


private void btnFind1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    deleg = this.find2;
    backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
}


private void btnFind2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    deleg = this.find1;
    backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
}

private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    BackgroundWorker bk = sender as BackgroundWorker;
    e.Result = deleg;

    if (bk.CancellationPending)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
}


private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Cancelled)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Operation was canceled");
    }
    else if (e.Error != null)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("An error occurred: " + e.Error.Message);
    }
    else
    {
        dataGridView1.DataSource = (DataTable)e.Result;
    }
}
```

So, basically I have 2 functions `find1` and `find2` and these are long-time-processing functions. I want to run these 2 functions on an `BackgroundThread` so I created a delegate. When i call one function, the delegate takes the address of a function or the other.
When I start the thread, I pass the delegate instead of directly typing the function, so I won't create 2 background threads, each with its own events and stuff.
But I run into problems, when I run the program, the following error is thrown:

```
"System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException was unhandled
Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation."
```

It has to do with the delegate passed to the thread. I can, of course, write everything simpler with conditions to see what functions has to be ran, but I got into this and I didn't know how to solve it. I want to know what I did wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, in your DoWork function, you need to call the delegate like this:

```
e.Result = deleg();
```

The reason is that this will actually invoke the function, rather than just set the result equal to a reference to the function.

Comment: Thank you, it solved the problem. I made a misjudgment there. 
Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You're casting a delegate to a `DataTable`:

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = (DataTable)e.Result;
```

which came from here:

```
e.Result = deleg;
```

Did you mean:

```
e.Result = deleg();
```